# Flink SQL client in application mode

Tags: flink-sql

Hi i'm new to Flink and my use case requires to use the flink sql client to write queries and execute it in a cluster. I was wondering if it is possible to use flink sql client with cluster in application mode and how to start it. Reading documentation it seems it is possible only on session mode as i should have to embedded the jar in a jobmanager.

Thanks.